# where is the "Edit Realm" page in GlassFish administration console?

Tags: console, glassfish, administration

in Java EE 6 & 7 tutorials, in chapter 47 **"Introduction to Security in the Java EE Platform "**, in section **"47.5.2.1 To Add Users to GlassFish Server"** it says "
On the Edit Realm page, click **Manage Users**. " ,
the question is i can not find this page (Realm page) in the administration console of GlassFish .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[image: edit realm]

The path to this navigation element is `server-config -> Security -> Realms`